# Is there a simple way to remove all packages that were received through a repository?

Tags: uninstall, repository

I just added a repository and did sudo apt-get update and upgrade...  but as soon as I finished typing I realized I didn't want all that junk it came with just a couple packages off the repository.  How can I remove it all if I don't know what all it installed?

Comment: If it's a PPA, use `ppa-purge`: http://askubuntu.com/a/313/158442

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy with Synaptic,  Click on `Origin` to split packages depending on whic h repository are coming from.

(Default is `Sections`)

[image: synaptic screenshot]